Work Done By Non-Conservative Forces Formula
Consider any non-conservative force, say friction, since the force is path dependent will the work done formula be altered accordingly. The formula for work done is $$W=\vec{F} \cdot \vec{s}\tag{1}$$
where $\vec{s}$ is the displacement but my question is , Can it be altered as $$W = F  \cdot d\tag{2}$$ where $d$ is the distance travelled. Is this true if the force is non-conservative?

Your formula for work is just a special case. You need to use integrals to express the work of general forces. See e.g. this answer of mine.

What is the question?

@Dale, The question is that can I use the formula Work= Force * Distance  in case of conservative forces

Hi Gaming Guru. Welcome to Phys.SE. To reopen this post (v4), consider to use precise notation to indicate vector vs. scalar quantities.

I see the question in the edits and have voted to reopen now

= ⃗  *   $^vec{F}d$ is a vector, W a scalar so in this form it is wrong. I F and d are in the same direction W=Fd is correct.

= ⃗  *   $^vec{F}d$ is a vector, W a scalar so in this form it is wrong. I F and d are in the same direction W=Fd is correct.

@ACuriousMind Is the Distance * Force formula correct atleast in this case?


Consider any non-conservative force, say friction, since the force is path dependent will the work done formula be altered accordingly.

The work formula does not change regardless of whether the force is conservative or not.

The formula for work done is $$W=\vec{F} \cdot \vec{s}\tag{1}$$

Yes, this is the correct formula.

Can it be altered as $$W = F  \cdot d\tag{2}$$

No, if $\vec F$ is not parallel to $\vec d$ then $W\ne F \cdot d$.
Regardless of whether the force is conservative or not you should use $W=\vec F \cdot \vec s$ for a constant force in a straight-line path or $W=\int \vec F \cdot d\vec s$ for work with a non-constant force or a non-straight-line path.

What to do in case if Distance along a curved path is given instead of the displacement in a non conservative force?

If you do not have enough information to calculate the above integral then you cannot calculate the work

Well, I have a book in which they have used a method which uses distance while calculating friction force and there are some questions online which do the same, So that means they are wrong?

@GamingGuru having enough information to calculate the integral doesn’t necessarily mean that you formally solve an integral. Often, due to some simplifications, the integral can be calculated some easier way. I suspect your book was using simplified circumstances

here is the problem which led me to this confusion as they used distance along the curve instead of the displacement.
https://i.sstatic.net/itDRmxIj.jpg

@GamingGuru what is the problem? They give you $s=12 \mathrm{\ m}$. I guess that you are supposed to assume that the magnitude of friction is constant. So from that you can calculate the integral. It seems vaguely worded since it doesn't explicitly state that you should assume it to be constant, but otherwise fine.

Here me out, I am a lower grade student ( 9th Grade) so I don't have much information about integrations but, according to your solution could you please solve it and tell me the result obtained, I'll see if it matches the answer of the solution.It would mean a lot to me
